# css layout - How to create a boundary around a ul element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create the following layout but not sure how to make it exactly looks like following.

[image]

> Html

```
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <ul>
                    <li class="pointer" routerLink="/market/b">
                        <i class="ri-shopping-basket-2-fill"></i>
                        <span>Warenkrob</span>
                        <span>0,00</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

> CSS

```
.entry-meta {
        .pointer {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .green {
            color: greenyellow;
        }

        .strike {
            text-decoration: line-through;
            color: #ff6347;
        }
        ul {
            padding-left: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            list-style-type: none;

            li {
                margin-right: 20px;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                color: $white-color;
                border-right: 1px solid #515151;
                font: {
                    weight: 500;
                    size: 16px;
                }
                padding: {
                    right: 20px;
                    left: 45px;
                }
                i {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    color: #cfcfcf;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 50%;
                    transform: translateY(-50%);

                    &:hover,
                    &:focus {
                        color: $main-color;
                    }
                }
                span {
                    display: block;
                    color: white;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    margin-bottom: 2px;
                    font: {
                        size: 14px;
                        weight: 600;
                    }
                }
                a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    color: $main-color;
                    font: {
                        size: 16px;
                        weight: 600;
                    }

                    &:hover,
                    &:focus {
                        color: $main-color;
                    }
                }
                &:last-child {
                    padding-right: 0;
                    margin-right: 0;
                    border-right: none;
                }

                .badge-notify {
                    background: $green-color;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0;
                    left: -10px;
                    bottom: -15px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 20px;
                    position: absolute;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why `<ul><li>` ? it's just my opinion but this basket layout has nothing to do with a list, hast it?

Comment: @caramba You are right. I was trying to achieve the layout using <ul><li>. Looking forward if there is a better way to do this

Comment: @caramba thx for pointing that out. i have corrected it. done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ul and li unless it's actually in a list. Here below is something I just threw together. I added a `transform: rotate` on the emoticon cart, so you need to style it separately with padding if you remove the transform.

If you want to update the counter, you can set the CSS variable `--shopping-cart-counter-items`.

```css
.shopping-cart.container {
  --shopping-cart-border: 2px solid #ccc;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: var(--shopping-cart-border);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.shopping-cart > * {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.shopping-cart > .image {
  --shopping-cart-counter-items: "3";
  --shopping-cart-counter-size: 20px;

  position: relative;
  border-left: var(--shopping-cart-border);
  font-size: 2rem;

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.shopping-cart > .image::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: var(--shopping-cart-counter-items);
  width: var(--shopping-cart-counter-size);
  height: var(--shopping-cart-counter-size);
  left: 40%;
  top: 0px;
  
  padding-top: 0.1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.shopping-cart > .information > * {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart container">

  <div class="image"></div>
  
  <div class="information">
    <div class="title">Shopping cart</div>
    <div class="amount">€ 30</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How can i add a badge on top of the cart as counter ?

Comment: I would use a pseudo-selector and display it on top of the cart. I updated the post accordingly. Do note, images don't have pseudo-selectors, so you need to put the image in a div container. You could also use a absolute positioned span - that would probably be easier AND can be read by someone using a text reader (accessibility!).

Comment: Just curious how you made that basket icon ?

Comment: @SaurabhKumar It's an emoticon. :) You can press CTRL+CMD+Space (Mac) to see them.